# form wizard does not move to the next screen in a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

I an using django-crispy forms and using that in a jquery dialog box to show a form wizard. the problem that I am facing is that when used in the dialog box the wizard never moves to the next screen.

So, my wizard is defined as follows:

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return "reviewdialog.html"


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('index')
```

And the template is defined as:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {% crispy form %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% crispy wizard.form %}
{% endif %}
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
</table>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value = "NEXT">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, I show this in a jquery dialog where I have overridden the `submit` method to ensure that the dialog does not close on clicking the 'NEXT' button

```
<script>
        function EditDialog(pk) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'populatereviewform' %}",
                method: 'GET',
                data: {
                pk: pk
            },
            success: function(formHtml){
                //place the populated form HTML in the modal body
                $('.modal-body').html(formHtml);
                $( "#dialog" ).modal({width: 500, height: 500});
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        });

            $('#dialog').submit( function(e) {
                return false;
            });

            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

The `AJAX` part just populates the form with some data and the `dialog` object is a standard `jquery modal` dialog. The form is shown at the first screen and is populated with the correct value but when I press `NEXT` nothing happens in the sense that the wizard does not transition.

The `urls.py` is configured as:

```
url(r'^review/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ContactWizard.as_view([DummyForm, OtherForm]), name='review'),
```

Som, the form starts with the `DummyForm` (which is a `ModalForm`) but does not progress to the next wizard screen. I have a feeling it could be something to do with my javascript but could bit get to the bottom of this.

**EDIT**

So, based on @udi's answer, I tried the following:

```
$("#dialog").submit(function(e)
            {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                        }
                    }
                });
                var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
                var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url : formURL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data : postData,
                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {
                        $('.modal-body').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        alert(errorThrown)
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
                e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
            });
            return false;
            }
```

However, the data that is returned here is not the next screen of the wizard but the underlying page on which the dialog is shown. So, perhaps it is the `formURL` or `postdata` variables that are not initialized properly?

The template for the wizard screen is:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form id="review-form" action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {% crispy form %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% crispy wizard.form %}
{% endif %}
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" class="btn btn-success" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" class="btn btn-success" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
</table>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value = "Hello">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You do not jquery or ajax. Just submit it like a regular form.

Comment: @sureshvv I thought that is what `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value = "NEXT">` would do. The thing is when I load the regular page, it works. it is only when it is embedded in the jquery dialog that it does not move to the next form.

Comment: why do u need a jquery dialog? The submit probably redirects to the page2 form and your ajax doesnt know to handle it.

Comment: @sureshvv The form is on a pop up dialog for various reasons. So, is there a way to get the response HTML for page2 of the form and I guess update the content of the jquery dialog?

Comment: Yes. It should be possible. But will be hard :) You may have to understand how the wizard operates. I think it stores all the form variables in the session. Do you get any error in your JS console? Can you stick a pdb breakpoint inside the POST and step thru?

Comment: hmmmmm... I am very new to this and it seems I have taken a complicated route. Will need to investigate and see how it goes. Will update the thread as soon as I find something

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get the html of the next form via jQuery and update it in the dialog.

Comment: How would one get the HTML? is it possible through an AJAX call?

Comment: Try using [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) and `$('.modal-body').html(hrml)` again.

Comment: I edited the post to highlight what I tried based on your answer.

Comment: Instead of rendering the url, get it from `$("form").attr('action')`

Comment: So, i tried something like: `var formURL = $("review-form").attr("action");
alert(formURL)` However, this returns `undefined`. The `review-form` is the form ID which is defined in another template but I am guessing that should not matter as this is the one loaded in the jquery dialog.

Comment: Try `$("#review-form").attr("action");` for `id="review-form"`

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it returns blank page with a ".". In the template, the form is defined as: `<form id="review-form" action="." method="post">`. I wonder if that has something to do with this. I am editing the question to add the full template. I am guessing it is returning the "." specified in the action field?